# HTML Form onSubmit being bypassed

Tags: javascript, html, github-pages

I'm new to HTML and JS and I'm trying to setup a "Contact" page using GitHub Pages. I am using [formspree.io](https://formspree.io/) to submit the forms and e-mail to the app mail account.

Here is the deal: I'm trying to setup a simple validation just to verify if the form fields aren't empty (there is no need for a server-side validation), but the "onSubmit" response seems to be bypassed every single time.

Here is my contact.html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {font-family: Helvetica;}
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

input[type=text], select, textarea {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-top: 6px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    resize: vertical;
}

input[type=submit] {
    background-color: #b00faa;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 15px;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #780774;
}

.container {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h3>Formulário de Contato</h3>

<div class="container">
  <form action="https://formspree.io/myEmailHere@mail.com" method="post" onsubmit="return validate();">
    <label for="fname">Nome Completo</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="Seu nome completo...">

    <label for="email">E-mail</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Seu e-mail...">

    <label for="subject">Mensagem</label>
    <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Digite algo..." style="height:200px"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
  </form>
</div>

<p id="error_catch"></p>

<script>
  function validate() {
    var at = document.getElementById("email").value.indexOf("@");
    var message = document.getElementById("subject").value;
    var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;

    if (fname.length < 1) {
      alert("Digite seu nome...");
      return false;
    }
    if (at === -1) {
        alert("E-mail inválido!");
        return false;
    }
    if (message.length < 1) {
      alert("Digite uma mensagem");
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

If I open the file locally on Google Chrome, it works just fine, the alerts show up and the form is not submitted until all fields have been filled.
When I open it on my GHPages, however, it bypasses the validate function and proceeds to Formspree captcha page.

A little bit more context (not sure if it influences)...

This file is being included on my index.html file using a JS function.
My index consists of 2 tabs that load a different HTML when clicked.
Here is the GitHub repo for more information: [TellMeApp/support](https://github.com/TellMeApp/support).

What I have already tried:

- Correcting the Javascript function: I am aware that if an error is raised on the function, the submission follows on without validation.
- Creating an additional function to submit the form via JS: works the same locally, not online...
- Looking for solutions on Github Pages help: did not found anything related to this subject.

Any thoughts on what could be wrong here?

I thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't recommend using onsubmit as an attribute, but it should look like this: `onsubmit="validate"`

Comment: Thanks @GetOffMyLawn, will try that!

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn While you're definitely right about not using event attributes, the rest of what you wrote is just not true. The string set on the attribute `onsubmit` gets evaluated as any other piece of code, and thus `"validate"` just references the function and accomplishes nothing. OP's code is correct.

Comment: @RafaelTomazPrado Since you mention it's working fine in Chrome when running locally, the issue isn't with your code but rather something related to having it hosted on and running from Github Pages

Comment: @Lennholm is right, changing the attribute did nothing. I still don't know if the problem is on GitHub Pages, but the answer from Devtician below sure worked. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the onsubmit attribute, you can use the required attribute for the inputs like so:

```
<label for="fname">Nome Completo</label>
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="Seu nome completo..." required>

<label for="email">E-mail</label>
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Seu e-mail..." required>

<label for="subject">Mensagem</label>
<textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Digite algo..." style="height:200px" required></textarea>
```

If you are interested in reading more about the required attribute, you can find it here: [HTML required Attribute - W3Schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp)

Comment: Thank you, I will try that!

Comment: Worked like a charm! And also, thanks for the reference link.